# SWT Balloon Tooltip on Iconified Shell

Tags: java, swt, system-tray

I am using openNotifi method to create balloon tooltips on tray icon, but they are also minimize when shell is iconified. How can i show notification tooltips even shell is iconified ?

```
    public void openNotifi() {      
    final ToolTip tip = new ToolTip(shell, SWT.BALLOON
            | SWT.ICON_INFORMATION);
    tip.setMessage("Here is a message for the user. When the message is too long it wraps. I should say something cool but nothing comes to my mind.");
    Tray tray = shell.getDisplay().getSystemTray();
    if (tray != null) {
        TrayItem item = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);
        ;
        tip.setText("Notification from a tray item");
        item.setToolTip(tip);
    } else {
        tip.setText("Notification from anywhere");
        tip.setLocation(100, 400);
    }
    tip.setVisible(true);
}
```

and callin it by

```
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
try {
    if (current_username != sender) {
        openNotifi();
    }
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i created an application window (non visible, not opened) and opened my main shell from it as child and created tooltips as child of nonvisible application window. I dont know if its the real solution but it works now.